# Why does an Autonomous System have many IP blocks located in many countries?

Tags: routing

As far as I am aware, Autonomous System Numbers (ASNs) are assigned to entities such as Internet Service Providers and other large organizations that control blocks of IP addresses. Thus, each ASN can be mapped to its country of location. For example, ASN174 is mapped to United States. However, when it check this page: http://ipinfo.io/AS174, this AS also controls many IP blocks that aren't located in United States (e.g. 5.83.240.0/20 is in Ireland, and 5.157.72.0/21 is in Slovenia). So my question is that where the ASN (i.e. the data center) is really located in, is it still in the United State? And, will the AS-paths that originate from IP block in Ireland and from IP block from Slovenia to a same destination host be totally different although they are from a same ASN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The country attribute in whois databases only indicates in which country the office which registered the AS number is located, it does not tell you anything about where traffic is originated.

Keep in mind that AS numbers are not limited to a country. Cogent (AS174) has points of presence all around the world, thus it has customers located all around the world, as you can see on the page you linked. ASn's are not limited to a country.
Most likely, they have set the country attribute for those IP blocks to the country in which the customer they assigned the block to prefers. This helps preventing localisation problems like seeing webpages in a wrong language.

Information in whois databases do not need to reflect the reality of the routing tables.

> And, will the AS-paths that originate from IP block in Ireland and from IP block from Slovenia to a same destination host be totally different although they are from a same ASN?

All IP blocks are originated from the same ASN (174). If the AS path for each prefix is identical is totally up to Cogent. They may choose to announce specific IP blocks to specific BGP peers or use the same policy for every IP block. The only way to tell is look at routing tables.

Answer (score 1):

An AS isn't limited to one datacenter. Large ISPs have globe-spanning networks, so they can move traffic arround the world while keeping it in-network. Therefore from the point of view of the rest of the internet their network can be treated as a single network.

Cogent are a transit free network, so to provide their customers with access to the internet* they will need to announce all their customers to all the other transit free networks that they peer with (and likely to most of the other networks they peer with though sometimes peering politics lead to only a subset of customer prefixes being announced) and similarly provide routes for outgoing traffic to all those peers.

Of course with many/most of their peers they will be interconnected in multiple locations. They will likely use some mechanisms (such as nearest-exit routing for outgoing traffic and/or multi-exit discriminators for incoming traffic and/or artificially extending the "AS path") to try and prevent traffic taking stupid routes (sending traffic across the atlantic twice is generally considered a way to annoy customers and waste money).

* Well most of it. They have an ongoing peering spat with HE and HE consider themselves to be an "IPv6 teir 1" and refuse to buy IPv6 transit. So there is no IPv6 connectivity between HE and cogent.